# Is this sentence from the BBC web site correct: "Internet supply is cutting in and out."?

Tags: grammar, meaning, idioms, phrases, idiomatic-language

This is from the BBC. [Drinking water from the Nile](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-65335747)

**"....So we have no running water and the electricity and internet supply is cutting in and out."...**

The expressions **"Internet supply is ...."** seemed unusual to me, I googled it, not many  usage this way, but because it is BBC, it must be correct. Still, I am confused and want to ask:

Is **"internet supply"** the right word? Wouldn't we say **"internet connection"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather odd.  You would say that the "power supply" to a house or the "fuel supply" to an engine is cutting in and out.  I'd agree that "internet connection" sounds better.

I can find others transferring the colocation "power supply" to "internet supply":

> The internet supply must be reliable so that remote workers can access On-Premises Services ([source](https://www.flex.co.uk/it-solutions/business-continuity/internet-supply))

All the examples I find are British.

Comment: I'm not sure if the BBC are just being careless or intending to distinguish internet supply from internet connection. I'd say "internet connection cutting in and out" could mean very short term breaks due to some kind of minor issue such as interference or heavy traffic, but "internet supply cutting in and out" might mean something more serious, like a physical disconnection, serious technical problem, or the whole service going down for hours.

Comment: 'Supply' feels like it covers a broader spectrum, affecting larger groups of people over a wider area than 'connection' - which could just be your own building, or a bad WiFi box. I think their intention is to make it sound 'more serious'.

Comment: An individual BBC correspondent, obviously coping with difficult circumstances, has chosen an unusual combination of words. Possibly he started to say _the electricity supply_ and added _and internet_ as an afterthought.